# JavaFX: Original layout of GridPane altered after switching scenes using getChildren().setAll()

Tags: javafx

To summarize, I have various FXML files and various corresponding controllers, and to switch between them I am using the following code:

```
@FXML
public void openInputPane() throws IOException {
    BorderPane inputMenu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("inputSection/firstPage/inputEquationMenu.fxml"));
    mainBorderPane.getChildren().setAll(inputMenu);
}
```

My main fxml file is a GridPane and the rest are BorderPanes, and this method of using .getChildren().setAll(anotherPane) works perfectly until I try to return to the main GridPane:

```
public void goToMainMenu() throws IOException {
        URL url = new File("C:\\Users\\Luisa" +
                "\\IdeaProjects\\IA\\src\\sample\\mainmenu.fxml").toURI().toURL();
        GridPane mainMenu = FXMLLoader.load(url);
        successMessageBorderPane.getChildren().setAll(mainMenu);
}
```

The above code does display the original main menu, but messes up the formatting, attached are pictures of the main menu when I first open the programme and the main menu after returning to it.

[after returning to main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCRDe.png)

[main at the start of the programme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auGtw.png)

My question is, what is messing up the formatting when I go back to the main page, and what do I have to do to fix it?

For more details I'm attaching the fxml file for the main GridPane and the last BorderPane (the one where a button is clicked to return to the main GridPane) and their respective controllers.

**mainmenu.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?> <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?> <?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?> <?import javafx.scene.text.Font?> <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            stylesheets="@resources/styles.css" fx:id="mainBorderPane" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="500" vgap="20"
          hgap="20" alignment="CENTER">

    <HBox GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
        <Label text="Physics Formula Storage">
            <font>
                <Font size="40"/>
            </font>
        </Label>
    </HBox>
    <HBox GridPane.rowIndex="1" spacing="35">
        <Button text="Insert Equations" onAction="#openInputPane"/>
        <Button text="Use Equations"/>
    </HBox>
    <HBox GridPane.rowIndex="2" spacing="20"
          prefWidth="340">
        <Label text="Input new equations along with their properties into the storage system" prefWidth="150"
               style= "-fx-font-size: 14"/>
        <Label text="Find and use equations already in the storage system" prefWidth="150" style= "-fx-font-size: 14"/>
    </HBox>

</GridPane>
```

**Controller**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    GridPane mainBorderPane;

    // switching to the input pane if the button is clicked
    @FXML
    public void openInputPane() throws IOException {
        BorderPane inputMenu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("inputSection/firstPage/inputEquationMenu.fxml"));
        mainBorderPane.getChildren().setAll(inputMenu);
    }
}
```

**successMessageMenu.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="sample.inputSection.thirdPage.SuccessMessageController"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" stylesheets="@../../resources/styles.css"
            fx:id="successMessageBorderPane">

    <padding>
        <Insets top="30" right="50" bottom="30" left="50"/>
    </padding>

    <top>
        <VBox prefHeight="50">
            <Label alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" text="Equation added successfully">
                <font>
                    <Font size="17"/>
                </font>
            </Label>
            <Line startX="50" startY="50" endX="550" endY="50"/>
        </VBox>
    </top>

    <center>
        <VBox prefHeight="300" alignment="CENTER">
            <Label text="Equation has been added successfully" style="-fx-font-style: italic">
                <font>
                    <Font size="40"/>
                </font>
            </Label>
        </VBox>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <VBox alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" prefHeight="50">
            <Button text="Return to main menu" fx:id="mainMenuButton"
                    onAction="#goToMainMenu"/>
        </VBox>
    </bottom>

</BorderPane>
```

**successMenuController**

```
public class SuccessMessageController {

    @FXML
    Button mainMenuButton;
    @FXML
    BorderPane successMessageBorderPane;

    public void goToMainMenu() throws IOException {
        URL url = new File("C:\\Users\\Luisa" +
                "\\IdeaProjects\\IA\\src\\sample\\mainmenu.fxml").toURI().toURL();
        GridPane mainMenu = FXMLLoader.load(url);
        successMessageBorderPane.getChildren().setAll(mainMenu);
    }

}
```

(it is my first time asking a question, do tell me if I need to add anymore code, thank you!)

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/sedj601/RestaurantOrdersDuplicateFX.

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you!